Can i use Gmail's "send later" function from the Thunderbird client?
Thunderbird sports a Send Later add-on, that allows one to send an email some hours later, or at a certain time/date, etc., but it requires Thunderbird (not to mention the computer itself) to be up and running at the time the message is to be sent.
One can use the above function also for Gmail, if the Gmail account is registered within the Thunderbird client (I use it through IMAP/SMTP).
Similarly but more conveniently, Gmail (either the app or the web interface) allows one to program the sending at a certain time, even if the phone or the pc will be off at that time. This is especially useful for those that might be on a plane at that time, or simply don't want the pc to stay on for a long time, e.g. to avoid wasting energy, for example during the night.
So, one that normally prefers the Thunderbird interface would like that it can "book" the sending from there, somehow interfacing to a send later API that I expect be available in Gmail.
Is there such function or anything similar, maybe within an extension? Or, can the existing "send later" extension be upgraded in this sense?
Thank you very much.
